# How do I change DeletionPolicy of imported resources so that subsequent imports work?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm currently in the process of importing our existing resources into a CloudFormation stack. To import a resource Foo, I describe its current state in the template, set the `DeletionPolicy` to `Retain`, then import the existing resource. So far, so good.

Now I want to remove the `DeletionPolicy` of the imported resource, so I remove it in the template and deploy it. This results in "No changes to deploy. Stack MyStack is up to date".

If I now try to import another resource, again following the above process, it fails with this error:

> **There was an error creating this change set**
> You have modified resources [Foo] in your template that are not being imported. Update, create or delete operations cannot be executed during import operations.

To me, this looks like the earlier deploy does not apply the DeletionPolicy change. If I keep the DeletionPolicy of Foo  as `Retain`, the import of later resources works as expected.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what are you exactly doing? I haven't observed such behavior. For me it works as expected - removing `DeletionPolicy` updated the stack as it should.

Comment: To remove the DeletionPolicy, I change the template and then use this command: `aws cloudformation deploy --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --template-file CloudFormation/template.yaml --stack-name MyStack`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to update the DeletionPolicy by doing a "direct update" through the CLI, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-direct.html), i.e. using `update-stack` instead of `deploy`.

It seems updating methods that work with change sets, such as `deploy` or the Update function of the Console don't work because DeletionPolicy apparently doesn't constitute a "real" change?

Comment: Bad luck if you've set up your entire CICD pipeline to use deploy, or to use change sets!